# Decode encoded text with ASCII

Tags: java, encoding, ascii, decode

I'm using below method to encode given text.

```
static long encodeText(String text) {
    long l = 31;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        l = l * 47 + text.getBytes()[i] % 97;
    }
    return l;
}
```

When i call above method as `encodeText("stackoverflow")`, return the encoded text `3818417496786881978`.

Now i want to provide encoded text and get String value. For example, if i give `3818417496786881978` to `decodeText(long encoded)`, i need to get output as `stackoverflow`.

```
static String decodeText(long encoded) {
    String str = null;
    // decode steps here
    return str;
}
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: That's simply not going to work given your current "encoding" scheme. If you want to actually encrypt something, use a real encryption API. (You've got other issues in terms of calling `text.getBytes()` without specifying an encoding, etc...)

Comment: what is the purpose of your encoding? is it encryption? if so, why don't use standard encryption mechanisms supported by java?

Comment: The problem is that you can't properly specify the delimiters in the number. If all text becomes a 2-digit number, then it's possible. If it's variable length, then there's a high chance it cannot be decoded.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you. So isn't there anyway to do this with my current encoding scheme ? if i call `text.getBytes("UTF-8")` ?

Comment: No - your encoding approach is basically too lossy. It's the sort of code which is used for hashing, not encryption.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov There is no special purpose for given encoding. These days i'm learning about `ciphertext`. so i wrote above code and now trying to find way to decode it.

Comment: @Greg in this case, for learning purposes, consider `XOR` operation for encoding. it is `^` operator in java.

Answer (score 0):

Think this through logically: the clear text "stackoverflow" when represented as 7-bit ASCII represents 13 times 7 bits (=91 bits) of information. Thats more than a long (64 bits) can hold. So your encoding will lose information, making decoding impossible.

That should be also quite apparent from the formula you use:

```
l = l * 47 + text.getBytes()[i] % 97;
```

For each charcter you get a number between 0 and 96 (you already loosing information in the modulo, reducing information to 97 possible characters (e.g. you cannot distinguish between the bytes 1 and 98 after the modulo any more). Then you multiply your long by a number less than 97 (47), so two consecutive characters will overlap in terms of information distribution in the cyphertext.
Finally, after adding more an more characters, the long simply overflows and the topmost bits are simply lost.

In conclusion: If you want to decode the cyphertext ever again, fix the loss of information in these three places.

Comment: `text.getBytes()` itself could be lossy, too. Do use `text.getBytes("UTF-8")`.